# onClick mat-select to load data makes blank screen

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-select which options are loaded when the `(click)` event is emmited. The options are loaded good but when I click and load the data I get a 0.1 second blank screen which is not nice. How can I solve this bug/issue? Here is the code for this:

***html***

```
<mat-form-field fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlex="1 1 32%">
              <mat-label i18n>Centro</mat-label>
              <mat-select #selectCentros formControlName="centro" i18n-placeholder placeholder="Seleccione centro" required (click)="loadCentros()">
                <mat-option *ngIf="!listaCentros.length>0"></mat-option>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let centro of listaCentros" [value]="centro">
                  {{centro.nombre}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

***typescript***

```
  loadCentros() {
    if (!this.loadedCentros)
      this.centrosService.list().subscribe(centros => {
        this.loadedCentros= true;
        if (centros)
        centros.forEach(centro => {
          this.listaCentros.push(centro as Centro);
        });
      })
  }
```

Comment: Provide stackblitz demo

Comment: I don't think is an error of coding, but is likely an angular trick/bug that I don't know yet how to solve @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Do you want to add values on just clicking on select tag?

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search-dx9btc Working fine!

Comment: Adapted the solution to my app and added mat-spinner while the timeout! Working fine! Thanks <3 Leave an answer if you want upvote @PrashantPimpale

Comment: But I did't change a bit from your code! If its working for you then glad it helped!